# Problem getting regex 'Not Word' to work with Apex string literals

Tags: regular-expressions, apex

I have this string 'Enterprise - SELA';
And I want to convert it to 'Enterprise_SELA';
I can do this with the regex: \W+

However

```
 original.replace('\W+', '_')
```

throws the

```
Illegal character sequence \W'
```

error and

```
original.replace('\\W+', '_')
```

doesn't carry out the replacement. Nor does original.replace('\\W+', '_')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `String.replaceAll`, not `String.replace`. `String.replace` only looks for a literal string.

```
String original = 'Enterprise - SELA';
String replaced = original.replaceAll('\\W+', '_');
```